# Unable to run inference on CPU for a saved model using Conv3D

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am in a unique situation. I have been handed a `saved_model.pb` file and asked to run inference on it on a CPU machine. Running `saved_model_cli` on it shows that the model has the following structure:

```
MetaGraphDef with tag-set: 'serve' contains the following SignatureDefs:

signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['image_bytes'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 1, 128, 128, 128)
        name: input_1:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['score_categories'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 5, 128, 128, 128)
        name: activation_1/Sigmoid:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict
```

Using `Tensorflow 2.0` I load the file using the following script:

```
MODEL_PATH = 'phase_2_model/'
loaded = tf.saved_model.load(MODEL_PATH)
infer = loaded.signatures["serving_default"]
```

And then use it to try to run inference:

```
labeling = infer(tf.constant(img))
```

where `img` has the shape `(1, 1, 128, 128, 128)`

However, running the inference on a CPU (without attaching a GPU) throws out the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  CPU implementation of Conv3D currently only supports the NHWC tensor format.
         [[node conv3d_1/Conv3D (defined at usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_pruned_3347]
```

I find this error to be strange since a `Conv3D` operation should take in an input in the `data_format='NDHWC'` but the error still wants the input to be in `NHWC` format.

Any help on solving this error would be appreciated.